# Ajax call in Openshift throws 404 error

Tags: ajax, http-status-code-404, openshift

I'm trying to make a simple Ajax call in my app on Openshift. This is my ajax call which is triggered by pressing a button:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'http://my-site-name.rhcloud.com/asciimo',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {attr:"value"}
});
```

And this is node in my server.js file:

```
self.createRoutes = function() {
    self.routes['/asciimo'] = function(req, res) { 
         res.send('done');
    };
};
```

Everything works when I go to my-site-name.rhcloud.com/asciimo, but if I click a button (to get there) I get:

```
POST http://my-site-name.rhcloud.com/asciimo 404 (Not Found)
```

even though the link clearly works on it's own.

Comment: You should use logs and check if there are errors.

Answer (score 1):

Change your method to GET

```
method: 'GET',
```

When you go to the URL directly in your browser, you are issuing a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: After the change I'm getting: GET http://bgl-boardgamelab.rhcloud.com/asciimo?attr=sdf 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: If you go to that link using your browser, you will get the same error. The problem is not your js code. Its either with bgl-boardgamelab.rhcloud.com, or you are using the API incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem was now. In ajax there is a POST request and `self.routes['/asciimo']` (given as a template by Openshift) deals with GET requests only. What solved the problem was simply rewriting my function as a separate POST function:

```
self.addpost = function() {
  self.app.post('/asciimo', function(req, res){
    res.send('done');
  });
};
```